# .htaccess: Backreference in RewriteCond to check for file existence?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritecond

I'm trying to match URLs of this type:

http://www.example.com/image/12345

I'd then like to check whether this file exists:

http://www.example.com/files/image_12345.jpg

If it does, I'd like to rewrite the URL to point to that file.

If it doesn't I'd like to rewrite the URL to point to my image-generating script:

http://www.example.com/img_gen.php?id=12345

Here's what I've got so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/image/([0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/files/images_%1.jpg !-f
RewriteRule ^image/([0-9]+)$ img_gen.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^image/([0-9]+)$ /files/images_$1.jpg [L]
```

But all I'm getting is a 404.

Comment: Have you tried creating and reviewing an Apache rewrite log?  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog - may help with diagnosis and you can paste the output in your question.

Comment: I wish I could, but I'm on a shared host.  Maybe I'll try it locally on a MAMP environment.

Comment: You can add the rewrite log commands to your .htaccess file - see the first answer so far

Answer (score 0):

If you can't figure out what your Rewrite Rules are doing you should enable RewriteLog with some increased verbosity:

```
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteLog "/var/log/rewrite.log"
```

This should give you a pretty good starting position in further investigation of what's going on wrong.